# List boundaries - what is the most Pythonic way?

Tags: python

I have a Python list and I want to check if a given index is out of bounds. Since I'm accepting user input I want to restrict the index to integers greater than or equal to 0. What is the most Pythonic way to do this? Currently, this is my solution:

```
def get_current_setting(self, slot):
    if slot < 0 or slot > len(self.current_settings) - 1:
        raise Exception("Error message...")
    return self.current_settings[slot]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just try and access the value, and you will get an `IndexError` if it's out of bounds. Any checks you want to do out of the ordinary, just do those beforehand manually.

```
def get_current_settings(self, slot):
    if slot < 0:
        raise IndexError(...)
    return self.my_list[slot]
```

Comment: Because negative indexing is allowed and I want to prohibit that.

Comment: @DylanKlomparens See my edit, just do that check, and let the rest of it be dealt with normally.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you can do both checks (lower and upper bound) at once, making the if-condition much more readable:

```
def get_current_setting(self, slot):
    if not 0 <= slot < len(self.current_settings):
        raise Exception("Error message...")
    return self.current_settings[slot]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd replace your if line with this:

```
  if slot not in range(len(self.my_list)):
```

Comment: Interesting approach... but note that this will have running time of O(n).

Comment: @tobias_k Not in Python 3.x, where `range()` objects are not lists, but special iterators. That said, I still think this is far less readable, and redundant - there is no need to check the end index as that will be done either way.